# Merging two text files and sorting it to a third file

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, merge

I'm trying to make a program that will merge two different text files into a third file which is sorted in ascending order. Here is what the two files have within them

File 1:  12 23 34 45 56 67 69 123 133

File 2: 4 5 10 20 35 44 100 130 150 160 180

And here is the code I have so far:

```
    try 
    {

        FileReader file1=new FileReader("D://School//text1.txt");   
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("D://School//text1.txt"));
        ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        Collections.sort(values);      //sorting the values 
        while(scan.hasNextInt()) values.add(scan.nextInt());

        FileReader file2=new FileReader("D://School//text2.txt");
        scan = new Scanner(new File("D://School//text2.txt")); 
        values = new ArrayList<>();
        Collections.sort(values);       //sorting the values. 
        while(scan.hasNextInt()) values.add(scan.nextInt());

        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader (file1);
        BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(file2);

        String temp1 = "";
        String temp2 = "";

        while(br1.readLine() !=null)
        {
            temp1=br1.readLine()+temp1;
        }
        while(br2.readLine()!=null)
        {
            temp2=br2.readLine()+temp2;
        }
        String temp = temp1 + temp2; 



        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("D://School//text3.txt"); 
        char buffer[]=new char[temp.length()];
        temp.getChars(0,temp.length(),buffer,0);                        
        fw.write(buffer);
        file1.close();
        file2.close();
        fw.close();
    } 

    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The program so far will be able to read and write the proper contents into the third file, however, it isn't sorting it into ascending order.

Here is what the program will print to the third file

```
12 23 34 45 56 67 69 123 133 4 5 10 20 35 44 100 130 150 160 180
```

I want it to be sorting it into the third file as so

```
4 5 10 12 20 23 34 35 44 45 56 67 69 100 123 130 133 150 160 180
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It won't print to the third file what you say it'll print to it.  I execute your code and the third file contains `nullnull`.  Or when I put all numbers on new lines, it'll contain `null123674523null16013044205`.

Comment: Which leads me to a question:  Are those numbers all on one line, or each on separate lines?

Comment: Put both data numbers onto the second line of the text file and it should print out to the third correctly. Also the numbers that it prints out onto the third file will all be on one line.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use TreeSet, and i saw some problem in your code.

```
TreeSet<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<Integer>();
while(scan.hasNextInt()) treeSet.add(scan.nextInt());
scan = new Scanner(new File("D://School//text2.txt")); 
//Do not new Collection!!!!!
while(scan.hasNextInt()) treeSet.add(scan.nextInt());
```

and you can for-each the collection

```
for (Integer i : treeSet) {
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

and you can try this, if you have jdk8.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
    Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("D://School//text1.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).forEach(x -> Arrays.asList(x.split(" ")).stream().forEach(y -> ints.add(Integer.parseInt(y))));
    Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("D://School//text2.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).forEach(x -> Arrays.asList(x.split(" ")).stream().forEach(y -> ints.add(Integer.parseInt(y))));
    Collections.sort(ints);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    ints.stream().map(x -> x + " ").forEach(sb::append);
    Files.write(Paths.get("D://School//text3.txt"),sb.toString().getBytes(),StandardOpenOption.WRITE,StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

Comment: Note: If there are duplicates in the text files, then you would lose this information using a TreeSet.

Comment: Very nice lambda solution!  Unfortunately it throws a NumberFormatException when the text1/text2 files have an empty first line (as described by the OP in a comment to the question).  But tbh, I really wonder if that empty line was part of the assignment or a workaround by the OP to make the data fit the buggy code :P  +1 either way :)

Comment: Yes, the empty line was a workaround. I'm still in the process of learning java, thanks for all the help so far guys :)

Comment: Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(""), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).stream().filter(z -> !z.equals("")).forEach(x ->Arrays.asList(x.split(" ")).stream().forEach(y -> ints.add(Integer.parseInt(y)))); can solve it by filter

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Collections.sort(values);` you are sorting an empty `ArrayList`.

You need to call `Collections.sort(values);` after you have added all the values to the `ArrayList`.

You can run these examples to test:

**Example 1**:

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

// sort the list first
Collections.sort(values);

values.add(5);
values.add(3);
values.add(8);
values.add(1);

System.out.println(values);
```

> Outputs: [5, 3, 8, 1]

**Example 2**:

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();

values.add(5);
values.add(3);
values.add(8);
values.add(1);

// sort the list now
Collections.sort(values);

System.out.println(values);
```

> Outputs: [1, 3, 5, 8]

Comment: That alone won't fix it, there's more problems with this code.

Comment: Would I be able to add the values directly from the text file instead of having to add each number individually within the source code?

Comment: Well, you have to parse them like you are doing now with the `scan.hasNextInt()`